# Docker: How to disable root user in container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, root

Delivering images to customers they usually make

```
$ docker-compose up -d
```

to deploy those in production. It is easy to get root and to see / modify all file quite easy:

```
$ docker-compose exec <service> /bin/sh
/bin/sh(root)# ...
```

How can I avoid for customers to get full access rights to all files as root when running the container. Maybe this is not possible at all in Docker but then it should at least be more complicated for users to get full access to anything inside the container.

Is there a best practice to intrdoce non root accounts in containers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t.  You can always run

```
docker exec -u 0 (container ID) sh
```

to get a root shell.  (Assuming the image has a shell, but almost all do.)

Also remember that anyone who can run any `docker` command can edit any file on the host, and from there can trivially become root, and can prod around in `/var/lib/docker` to their heart’s content.

It’s generally considered good practice to set containers to run as non-root by `RUN adduser` to create a user using the base distribution’s tools and then a Dockerfile `USER` directive, but an operator can override this at runtime if they really want to.